# Getting id with $_POST - Is it possible?

Tags: php, post

Have this form:

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" id="form_pesquisa" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    <div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="cliente"  id="73"  value="ss">  "ss" </label> </div>
    <div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="cliente"  id="74"  value="aa">  "aa" </label> </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="hchoose">Choose client</button>
```

How can I get the id of the radio when the button is pressed? `$_POST['id']` does not work. Tks all.

Comment: What's "ss" and "aa"? What "radio" are you talking about? What "button" are yu talking about (maybe submit button)?

Comment: <div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="cliente"  id="73"  value="ssssssssssssss">  "ssssssssssssss" </label> </div><div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="cliente"  id="74"  value="aaaaaaaaa">  "aaaaaaaaa" </label> </div>

Comment: Tks Rajdeep Paul for your hand. Will do with JavaScript to get the id´s. Tks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` doesn't get passes to the server for processing, only the input **name** and **value** get passed. PHP uses `name` to process the user input & `$_POST['anything']` is used to get the **user input** of `<input type="radio" name="anything" id="73">` & not the `id="73"`. JavaScript can be used to get the id but not PHP actually.

If you really want to get whatever is in the `id` you can put it in value like `value="ssId-73"`

Comment: Tks Arsalan for your hand. Tks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `name` for the button eg. `<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton"/>` then in PHP `$_POST['myRadioButton']`

There's no way to receive id in PHP, you can only set same `name` as `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit your form (which will be the easiest way), you'll have to use jQuery, because using native Javascript will make it even more difficult.

Below your form:

```
<script src="jQuery_url">
</script>
<script>
    jQuery("#form_pesquisa").on("submit", function() {
        var id = jQuery("input[name='cliente']:checked").attr("id");
        jQuery(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+id+"'>");
    });
</script>
```

Having done this, in your form handler file, `$_POST['id']` will contain the value you want to catch.

Comment: Tks Eduardo for the idea. Tks a lot!